# Wifi instability (interruptions) on HP pavilion dv6

Tags: wireless, 16.04, connection, disconnect

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my old HP pavilion dv6 laptop. I have a very crucial and annoying problem with the wifi connection whenever I am at a public place (coffee shops, libraries...etc).

After I make a connection by wifi, it keeps switching on/off -- i.e. interrupting. This is seriously very annoying and impractical to say the least.

Can anyone assist me how to properly address and fix this issue ? I am a newbie on Ubuntu related manners, but would like to expand my knowledge !!

Answer (score 0):

```
Airmon-ng
Airmon-ng stop
Airmon-ng start wlan0 ( use your wlan interface )
Service network-manager restart
```

Restart your laptop, clear browser cookies to for optimal browsing 
experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with an hp laptop that I have, but it also happens in windows too. Does it occur in windows too for you? I searched on the internet and it appears to be a firmware issue with the hp laptop itself..  if you have another laptop try it on there and see if you have the issue still.

Comment: thanks! I have a partitioned HD and it is split almost equally between Ubuntu and Windows 10. Fortunately things run smoothly connection-wise on my windows OS :/